# can unary predicate for remove_if have sideeffects?

Tags: c++, stl

If those arent modifying the container?
For example I want to output all the ints I'm removing from a vector(and I dont want to use multiple  passes: eg: partition + output + erase). 
Design horribadness aside is this legal:

```
v.erase(remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [] (const int i) -> bool 
                                  { 
                                    if (i%2==0)
                                    {
                                       cout << i << endl;
                                       return true;
                                    }
                                    else return false;
                                   }, v.end());
```

AFAIK standard guarantees exactly one application of a predicate on each element so I am fine, since I dont care about the order...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard does indeed guarantee that, so you are fine. I would still consider it bad style except for debugging, though.

Comment: I was arguing with a colleague that is a fan of C :) so you know how that goes... like I said I would prob use partition + cout + erase in real code... :)  This was just perf question in a sense. :D

Comment: if you think partition + couting + erase is bad please say so i can edit the Q

Comment: No, partition, then couting the end before erasing it is exactly how I would do it.